# Any useful CASE tool for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, project-management, case

I'm a MAC user (not a fan :D) .. and I'm working these days on my graduation project in B.sc degree of Computer Science, and specifically I'm in the design phase. I've looked for CASE tools that should help me on my work, but unfortunately it seems there are no powerful CASE tools available!

could anyone suggest a good tool for me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Indeed, fans would never use an acronym for a name that isn't one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at cross platform tools based on Java, specifically, tools which are based on the Eclipse platform. Eclipse runs really well on OS X, in fact, I believe it works even better than it does on Windows. Not all Eclipse-based tools will run on Mac (for example, Rational will not), but most will.

Look at the [Eclipse Marketplace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/) for some popular tools for [UML](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/taxonomy/term/19), [modeling](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/category/categories/modeling-tools), etc.

Answer (score 0):

While this is likely to be closed as off-topic, you should see the other [closed discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18814/best-uml-application-for-mac-osx-cross-platform) or Apple's [Visio replacement](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2820/what-are-mac-os-replacements-for-visio/92443) threads.

Summary is:

- [OmniGraffle](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omnigraffle/feature_comparison/) for general, commercial diagramming.
- Eclipse based tools, as most UML is for writing the bulky Java code.
- Web based tools such as [GenMyModel](http://www.genmymodel.com) and [Gliffy](https://www.gliffy.com).
- Any from the long list on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools).

As always, the exact needs you have will dictate your tool.